# Discord.py default emoji reactions

Tags: discord.py

This code works for adding roles through reactions but I can only use custom emotes for reactions in the `payload.emoji.name` so when I set it equal to electric_plug it doesn't work. Is there any way around it?

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 799030902302834698:
      guild_id = payload.guild_id
      guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds) 
    if payload.emoji.name == 'electric_plug':
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Electrical')
      if role is not None:
        member = payload.member
        if member is not None:
          await member.add_roles(role)
        else:
          print('no member')
      else:
        print('no role')
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "electric_plug" name for the unicode emoji. Unicode emojis look like this:

You can get a unicode emoji in two ways.

First, you can just look through emojipedia and search for your wanted emoji. After that, just copy the one they provide (the box should look like this):

[image: Screenshot of copy and paste section of emojipedia]

The second option is going to discord, typing out your wanted unicode emoji normally (ex. ":thumbsup:"), and then placing a backslash (`\`) before it. Similar to this:

[image: Screenshot of discord after following instructions]

After that, send it, and copy the emoji that shows up. It should look different than the version of the emoji you usually see on Discord.

Once you've obtained your emoji, your code should look like this:

```
if payload.emoji.name == "":
```